# Malformed Json exception on gradle installDebug task in Android studio 2.2

Tags: android, json, android-gradle-plugin

I have currently update android studio to 2.2 and now I am getting this error

```
Error:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 188

Error:com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 188
```

I haven't used gson in my project but still I am getting this error. Any help?

[image]

Comment: Are you reading json from resources or using services to retrieve

Comment: Yes. But this is not the case. I get it for each project. It was working fine before update.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I'm not using any kind of json in my app. This just started happening out of a sudden.

Comment: I restarted Android Studio then it worked.

Comment: Yea. It goes away for some time but not permanently.